# wxWidgets alpha channel of wxColor not working as expected

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, wxwidgets, rgba

When setting a panel's BackgroundColor to wxColor(0,0,0,0). It seems to not be completely transparent.

I have a simple setup, I used the helloWorld example to illustrate my problem,
I have a frame, with 2 panels like this:

```
wxPanel *panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(150, 100), NULL, wxString::Format("panel1"));
wxPanel *panel2 = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxPoint(155,0) , wxSize(150, 100), NULL, wxString::Format("panel2"));
```

[image]

As you can see I have set the BackgroundColor of the frame to green using SetBackgroundColour:

```cpp
this->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(0,255,0,255));
```

Now I will try to make both panels transparent using SetBackgroundColour:

```cpp
panel->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(0,0,0,0));
panel2->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(255,0,0,0));
```

The expected result would be to have an all green screen, as the panels would be transparent, you would see the green frame, but instead of that I can still see the 2 panels in a slightly different colour green:

[image]

I'm not as much looking for a solution as I'm looking for an explanation as to why this happens.

To try it out here is the source code of the hello world example including my code:

```
// Start of wxWidgets "Hello World" Program
#include <wx/wx.h>
 
class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    bool OnInit() override;
};
 
IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
DECLARE_APP(MyApp);
 
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame();
 
private:
    void OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);
};
 
enum
{
    ID_Hello = 1
};
 
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame();
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}
 
MyFrame::MyFrame()
    : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "Hello World")
{

    wxPanel *panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(150, 100), NULL, wxString::Format("panel1"));
    wxPanel *panel2 = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxPoint(155,0) , wxSize(150, 100), NULL, wxString::Format("panel2"));
    
    panel->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(0,0,0,0));
    panel2->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(255,0,0,0));
    this->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(0,255,0,255));

    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;
    menuFile->Append(ID_Hello, "&Hello...\tCtrl-H",
                     "Help string shown in status bar for this menu item");
    menuFile->AppendSeparator();
    menuFile->Append(wxID_EXIT);
 
    wxMenu *menuHelp = new wxMenu;
    menuHelp->Append(wxID_ABOUT);
 
    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    menuBar->Append(menuFile, "&File");
    menuBar->Append(menuHelp, "&Help");
 
    SetMenuBar( menuBar );
   
    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText("Welcome to wxWidgets!");
 
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnHello, this, ID_Hello);
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnAbout, this, wxID_ABOUT);
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnExit, this, wxID_EXIT);
}
 
void MyFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Close(true);
}
 
void MyFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxMessageBox("This is a wxWidgets Hello World example",
                 "About Hello World", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}
 
void MyFrame::OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxLogMessage("Hello world from wxWidgets!");
}
```

I'm compiling this on macos using `` g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp `wx-config --cxxflags --libs` ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for overlapping (semi)transparent windows in wxWidgets. If you need transparency effects you need to use `wxGraphicsContext` and things yourself, but this is just not going to work with the standard native windows.